# Combobox dropdown don't visible as expected in windows mobile app (c#)

Tags: c#, combobox

What I need is to move other gui controllers down when I click on the combobox, so that I can clearly see the data inside the combobox.  I'm doing this on a windows mobile 8.1 project.

```
</Grid>     
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxCompanyLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" FontSize="13.333" Height="56" Margin="142,87,0,0" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyCity" PlaceholderText="Select a Location"/>

<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockCompanyLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,78" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Location" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.089,-0.581" FontSize="17.333" Height="38"/>

<Button x:Name="buttonFilterSearch" Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonFilterSearch_Click" Width="104"/>

<Button x:Name="buttonResetFilter" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="buttonResetFilter_Click" Width="94"/>

 </Grid>
```

Comment: Add more details of the exact problem in clear words. Show the code you have so far. Add more details of the UI to explain the issue.

Comment: Please read the help section on asking questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask